# Error matplotlib.pyplot spectrogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy realizando un analizador de espectro de audio en python, sin embargo me encuentro con 2 problemas.

1.- No lee la información de archivos mp3.
2.- Al cambiar el archivo que recibe por un archivo de 2 canales de audio me arroja un error.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import soundfile as sf

data, samplerate = sf.read('Close Your Eyes.flac',channels=2,samplerate=44100,
                           subtype='FLOAT')
y = data
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(y, NFFT=512, Fs=samplerate, cmap="inferno")
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10,6)
plt.xlim(0, len(y) / samplerate)
plt.ylim(0, samplerate/2)
plt.colorbar(im).set_label('Intensidad (dB)')
plt.xlabel('Tiempo (s)')
plt.ylabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
plt.show()
```

Y este es el error que genera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en los parámetros que le pasas a `sf.read()`. Le estás especificando cosas como el número de canales o la frecuencia de muestreo del fichero que estás leyendo, pero eso no son cosas que debas especificarle ya que él mismo las averigua del propio fichero. De hecho, si te fijas en el mensaje de error te dice que:

> TypeError: Not allowed for existing files (except 'RAW'): samplerate, channels, format, subtype, endian

Es decir, no puedes especificarle `samplerate` ni `channels` ni `format` ni `subtype` ni `endian` a la hora de abrir un fichero ya existente, salvo si el fichero es de tipo `RAW` (ya que en ese caso esa información no está disponible en el fichero y no la puede averiguar, por lo que se la tienes que dar).

Yo he leído sin problemas [este archivo FLAC de ejemplo](http://www.lindberg.no/hires/test/2L-125_stereo-44k-16b_04.flac) con la siguiente línea:

```
data, samplerate = sf.read('2L-125_stereo-44k-16b_04.flac')
```

Ahora bien. Lo que obtienes en `data` ya no es una lista de valores (las *samples*), sino una matriz de dos dimensiones, en concreto, dos columnas por `N` filas, siendo `N` el número de *samples* del fichero. La primera columna contiene el audio del canal izquierdo y  la segunda columna contiene el audio del canal derecho.

Ya que el resultado de `sf.read()` es un array numpy, puedes ver cuántas dimensiones tiene el array y el número de filas y columnas con:

```
>>> data.shape
(4311216, 2)
```

En mi caso tengo `4311216` filas (*samples*) y las 2 columnas mencionadas.

No puedes hacer el espectrograma de una señal bidimensional, pero tienes alternativas:

1. Haz el espectrograma de un solo canal (izquierdo o derecho)
2. Combina los dos canales con alguna fórmula de modo que te salga un resultado unidimensional. Por ejemplo, para cada pareja de *samples* (izquierdo, derecho) hacer su promedio: (izquierdo+derecho)/2

Veamos ejemplos de código y resultados en cada caso:

#### Espectrogramas separados para cada canal

Basta usar la notación de *slices* de numpy para quedarse con la columna 0 o la columna 1 de los datos:

```
y = data[:, 0]
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(y, NFFT=512, Fs=samplerate, cmap="inferno")
# ...
plt.show()
```

Canal izquierdo:
[image: canal izquierdo]

```
y = data[:, 1]
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(y, NFFT=512, Fs=samplerate, cmap="inferno")
# ...
plt.show()
```

Canal derecho:
[image: canal derecho]

#### Combinar los dos canales

Basta usar la función `sum()` de numpy, especificándole `axis=1` para que vaya sumando por filas en lugar de por columnas. El resultado será un array con la suma de los canales. Lo dividimos por dos y listo:

```
y = data.sum(axis=1)/2
Pxx, freqs, bins, im = plt.specgram(y, NFFT=512, Fs=samplerate, cmap="inferno")
# ...
plt.show()
```

Conversión a "mono":
[image: mono]

Respecto a lo de leer un .mp3, por desgracia `soundfile` no es capaz de hacerlo, y en general es difícil encontrar bibliotecas de código abierto que te permitan hacerlo porque MP3 está protegido por patentes. La recomendación es que uses un conversor (fuera de python) para pasarlo a un formato que `soundfile` pueda cargar. Por ejemplo `ogg`. Puedes hacer que tu programa python llame a la aplicación externa para hacer la conversión, usando `os.system()` por ejemplo.